# Condor Timeout for idle jobs

Tags: condor

I'm running jobs on a condor cluster, but some get hung in an idle state and never seem to start, let alone finish.  Short of manually doing `condor_wait -wait n logfile`, then `condor_rm`, is there a more graceful (and automatic, built in) way of terminating a hung job?

Conversely, since these jobs are in a dagman, is there a way to timeout a job in a dagman so that the later jobs can run?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to cause a job to be automatically removed after being idle for too long (24 hours in this example).

1. Put the following in the submit file for the job:

   periodic_remove = JobStatus == 1 && CurrentTime-EnteredCurrentStatus > 3600*24
2. Or put the following in the condor configuration file on the submit machine:

   SYSTEM_PERIODIC_REMOVE = JobStatus == 1 && CurrentTime-EnteredCurrentStatus > 3600*24

Of course, it would be better to understand why the jobs are remaining in the idle state.  To do that, you may find `condor_q -analyze jobid` helpful.