# Restart job in Condor after certain amount time

Tags: condor

I am running jobs on Condor and have noticed that for some reason a subset of my jobs will run but never complete.  Is there a setting in the submit file that kills and then resubmits a job if it takes over a certain amount of time to complete?  This is similar to the question [Condor Timeout for idle jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763866/condor-timeout-for-idle-jobs)
except I want Condor not to simply kill the jobs, but resubmit them as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the KILL transition expression in the machine class add file ([Condor user manual](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.6/3_5Policy_Configuration.html#SECTION00458000000000000000)). Something like:

```
START = True
...
+MaxJobExecutionTime = xxx #seconds
KILL            = $(ActivityTimer) > MaxJobExecutionTime
```

Like this the machine will kill jobs that take more than MaxExecutionTime. Condor will then retry the job.